# Alternatives to ajaxStart & ajaxComplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on implementing a progress bar. The current version of it that I found online uses ajaxStart to initiate the bar and set the start value an then ajaxComplete to animate and finish the bar.

I have a workflow function and I want to be able to set how far the bar should be at each step. Is this possible? I would need some way of using ajaxStart and then modifying it multiple times before the function ends and ajaxComplete takes place.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    //only add progress bar if added yet.
    if ($("#progress").length === 0) {
        $("body").append($("<div><dt/><dd/></div>").attr("id", "progress"));
        $("#progress").width((50 + Math.random() * 30) + "%");
    }
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    //End loading animation
    $("#progress").width("101%").delay(200).fadeOut(400, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not just start the progress when you begin your multi-step function rather than relying on ajaxstart/stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into SignalR, its a new library for real time updating of pages.

You can use it for this kind of thing and it will use websockets which gives you a background connection that updates regularly.

Also if the browser doesn't support web sockets then it falls back to older technologies:

- http://signalr.net/

Here is a tutorial that shows how to create a progress bar with it:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852586.aspx